# Streaming point clouds to webservice with roslibjs

Tags: ros, ros3djs, tf2, roslibjs, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that I want the rostopic `/camera/depth/points`. If I `rostopic echo /camera/depth/points` then I can see that data in bash. I can also get the [roslibjs example](http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs/Tutorials/BasicRosFunctionality) working just fine. I'm working across multiple machines so unfortunately ros3djs was not an option for me (*you can only render pointclouds on the localhost due to webgl limitations - more details at bottom of this question).

Good news is that I only want the data so I'm hoping to benifit from some of the ros3djs encoding. Anyway, I tried using roslibjs with object type `std_msgs/PointCloud2` to no avail:

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1477400298.863397] [Client 0] [id: subscribe:/camera/depth/points:1] subscribe: Unable to import msg class PointCloud2 from package std_msgs. Caused by 'module' object has no attribute 'PointCloud2'
```

How can I get my pointcloud data from my ros instance on one machine to a non-ros machine using this webservice?

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.robotwebtools.org/EventEmitter2/current/eventemitter2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.robotwebtools.org/roslibjs/current/roslib.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" type="text/javascript">
  // Connecting to ROS
  // -----------------

  var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
    url : 'ws://192.168.1.100:9090'
  });

  ros.on('connection', function() {
    console.log('Connected to websocket server.');
  });

  ros.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('Error connecting to websocket server: ', error);
  });

  ros.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection to websocket server closed.');
  });

  // Subscribing to a Topic
  // ----------------------

  var listener = new ROSLIB.Topic({
    ros : ros,
    name : '/camera/depth/points',
    messageType : 'std_msgs/PointCloud2'
  });

  listener.subscribe(function(message) {
    console.log('Received message on ' + listener.name + ': ' + message.data);
    listener.unsubscribe();
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Simple roslib Example</h1>
  <p>Check your Web Console for output.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

*(from the ros3djs example) Due to a bug in the current WebGL implementations, it is not possible to serve
this file and the video stream from a different host or port number, so we need ros_web_video
to serve the html file as well. If you use Apache, you can set it up to proxy port 9999 to a subdirectory.

## -- UPDATE --

My issue is definitely because I'm not running [tf2_web_republisher](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2_web_republisher) but I'm having a hard time getting it installed. I tried cloning the source to `~/catkin_ws/src`, `catkin_make`, `source ~/.bashrc` with no success.

How do I get the tf2_web_republisher tool installed? I've already `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-tf2*`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246402/streaming-point-clouds-to-webservice-with-roslibjs/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had to uninstall ubuntu 16.04 and move back to 14.04 so I could install ros-indigo because as far as I can tell, this setup ONLY works on indigo.

The package I was looking for is:

`ros-indigo-tf2-web-republisher`

---

Originally posted by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) with karma: 396 on 2016-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0